# rtsp streaming vlc in html page; fullscreen function

Tags: javascript, html, rtsp

I am building a website that shows a live streaming video. I want to build a single button of it to make a fullscreen of this live streaming.

These are my code:

```
<title>VLC Mozilla plugin test page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab">
        <!--param name="autostart" value="true" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" /-->
        <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
        name="video2"               
        pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
        version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" 
        autoplay="yes" fullscreen="false" volume="false"
        width="720"height="480" id="vlc" events="True" src="rtsp://100.100.100/video.something"/></embed>

    </object>
        <button>
        fullscreen
        </button>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("button").on('click', function(){
            var video = $('object').find('embed');
                console.log("founded");
                video.fullscreen = true;
                if(video.fullscreen === true){
                    console.log('fullscreen now');
                } else
                    console.log('fullscreen not now');


            });
        });
    </script>   

</body>
```

it cant work properly. I am so thankfull for every single advice :)

Comment: Please explain what error you are getting or problem you are facing.

Comment: ReferenceError: video is not defined ; I got that on the console. It won't show a fullscreen mode of that live streaming

Comment: Also explain what you have tried and why that didn't work out, but how it perhaps took you closer to a working solution.

Comment: @rovanion so, as you can see on the embed, the fullscreen is diactivated. So the user cant have a fullscreen modus directly on the VLC Plugin. when I click the button, on the console showed that video is not defined. the task is I should activate the fullscreen on this button and show the video in fullscreen modus.

Answer (score 0):

solved guys! It is not a best way, but it works! I deleted the fullscreen='true' on the embed; put an id for it and my a new javascript.

here is the new one:

```
<title>VLC Mozilla plugin test page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab">
        <!--param name="autostart" value="true" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" /-->
        <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
        id="vlc" 

        pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
        version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" 
        width="720"height="480" id="vlc" events="True" src="rtsp://host/video.something"/></embed>

    </object>
        <button id="fullscreen">
        fullscreen
        </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#fullscreen").click(function () { 
            var a = document.getElementById('vlc').video.toggleFullscreen(); 
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

but the problem is, it still shows a button fullscreen on the vlc plugin. I just still to find out how I can disable the fullscreen button on the vlc plugin and make my own button for this fullscreen.